# Why anglar.mock.module does not $provide values like it $provides constants

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I've looked at the documentation for [angular.mock.module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module) and a couple of [examples](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/05/27/ngmock-fundamentals-angularjs-testing-inject/) of [others](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/how-to-mock-providers-in-angular) using it but I seem to be running into an issue in my use-case that I don't understand.

I'm running Jasmine (`2.4.1`) tests with angular (`1.4.9`) and I have my angular app separated into multiple modules. When I attempt to mock out certain parts of my app for unit testing I want to mock out entire modules (or providers) so that I only expose the pieces I use.

Here is a very simple app that has a main module `plunker` which depends on `plunker.service`. `plunker.service` depends on `plunker.constant`.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['plunker.service']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, valueService, appService) {
  $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.appValue = valueService.getValue();
    $scope.appIsRunning = appService.getStatus();
  };
});

angular.module('plunker.service', ['plunker.constant'])
  .service('appService', function(appSettings) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.getStatus = function () {
      if (appSettings.isRunning) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    };
  })
  .service('valueService', function(valueSettings) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.getValue = function () {
      return valueSettings.value;
    }
  });

angular.module('plunker.constant', [])
  .constant('appSettings', { isRunning: true })
  .constant('valueSettings', { value: 10 });
```

In my Jasmine tests I have a `beforeEach()` that registers my modules using `module` (aka `angular.mock.module`).

I have seen 3 ways of using `module`

- `string`
- `function` with `$provide`
- `object`

You can see below that I use the `module('plunker')` (`string`) to register my main module and I have 3 ways of mocking out my `appSettings` constant (`A`, `B`, `C`). You will notice that the `function` with `$provide.constant` works fine but `function` with `$provide.value` does not and `object` does not.

```js
beforeEach(function() {
    module('plunker');

    function useFunction(typeofProvider) {
      module(function($provide) {
        $provide[typeofProvider]('appSettings', { isRunning: false });
      });
    }

    function useObject() {
      module({
        appSettings: { isRunning: false }
      });
    }

    // A. THIS WORKS! //
    useFunction('constant');

    // B. THIS DOES NOT //
    // useFunction('value');

    // C. THIS ALSO DOES NOT!! //
    // useObject();

    inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();

      ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: $scope
      });
    });  
});
```

I have also seen people use the following syntax...

```js
beforeEach(function() {
    var mockService = function () {
        var mockValue = 10;

        this.value = mockValue;
    };

    // D.
    module('a.module.name', function newProviders($provide){
        $provide.service('realService', mockService);
    });
});
```

My questions

1. In my test code, why does `A.` work but `B.` and `C.` do not?
2. Is `D.` equivalent to calling `module('a.module.name');` followed by `module(function newProviders($provide) { ... });`? Does placing both in the same `module()` call have any special effects on how things are registered or is it just a shorthand? (based on the documentation it should be a shorthand)
3. Related to Jasmine, specifically, do all `beforeEach()` calls run in the same top-to-bottom order with every execution?

Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1LlOqy?p=preview) for the above app and jasmine code

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of how Angular injector works. In fact, there are two different injectors in Angular. [The one](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.5/src/auto/injector.js#L652) (available as `$injector` in `config` blocks) deals with service providers. [Another one](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.5/src/auto/injector.js#L660) (available as `$injector` anywhere else) deals with service instances. [Providers](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.5/src/auto/injector.js#L642) and [instances](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.5/src/auto/injector.js#L659) are cached and stored internally.

`$provide.constant('service')` creates [both provider and instance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.5/src/auto/injector.js#L727) of name 'service' at call time.

All other types of services are lazily instantiated. They create 'serviceProvider' provider at call time, but 'service' instance is created on the first injection.

Since Angular service instance is a singleton, it refers to instance cache before the instantiation. If the instance is in the cache, it is reused and not instantiated. `constant` service instance is eagerly instantiated, so only another `constant` can override the instance.

Object properties in `angular.mock.module` [are shortcuts for `$provide.value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module#usage), and `useObject()` equals to `useFunction('value')` in this example.

As long as module order stays the same,

```
module('a.module.name', function ($provide) { ... });
```

is indeed a shortcut for

```
module('a.module.name');
module(function ($provide) { ... });
```

Due to the fact that `appSettings` object isn't used in `config` blocks (the primary use of `constant` service), it is more convenient to make it `value`.